# SOQL query causes internal Salesforce error

Tags: apex, soql, error

I've hit an unhandled exception when writing a query, and I'm curious if anyone here has seen the same thing.  This is not a timeout issue - the error happens almost immediately, so it's not a query efficiency issue.  The following query causes an "Internal Salesforce.com Error":
(Note that `End_Client__c` is an Account lookup on Opportunity, and `accountIds` is a `Set<Id>` of parents of both Account and End Client)

```
[
    SELECT Name
    FROM Account
    WHERE Id != :opp.AccountId
        AND Id != :opp.End_Client__c
        AND (
            Id IN :accountIds
            OR ParentId IN :accountIds
            OR Parent.ParentId IN :accountIds
            OR Parent.Parent.ParentId IN :accountIds
            OR Parent.Parent.Parent.ParentId IN :accountIds
        )
    ORDER By Name
]
```

However, it is fixed if I reduce the number of items in the OR chain to 2, regardless of which items I select.  This means the merge fields are not the issue causing the error. The following works successfully:

```
[
    SELECT Name
    FROM Account
    WHERE Id != :opp.AccountId
        AND Id != :opp.End_Client__c
        AND (
            OR Parent.Parent.ParentId IN :accountIds
            OR Parent.Parent.Parent.ParentId IN :accountIds
        )
    ORDER By Name
]
```

I was fortunately able to find a workaround, which has left me even more confused.  I changed the query to less efficient logic.  The query below evaluates properly, which suggests to me that the query parser is failing.

```
[
    SELECT Name
    FROM Account
    WHERE (Id != :opp.AccountId
        AND Id != :opp.End_Client__c
        AND Id IN :accountIds)
    OR
        (Id != :opp.AccountId
        AND Id != :opp.End_Client__c
        AND ParentId IN :accountIds)
    OR
        (Id != :opp.AccountId
        AND Id != :opp.End_Client__c
        AND Parent.ParentId IN :accountIds)
    OR
        (Id != :opp.AccountId
        AND Id != :opp.End_Client__c
        AND Parent.Parent.ParentId IN :accountIds)
    OR
        (Id != :opp.AccountId
        AND Id != :opp.End_Client__c
        AND Parent.Parent.Parent.ParentId IN :accountIds)
    ORDER By Name
]
```

Can anyone shed some light on what is going on here?

Comment: How many items are in your `Set<Id>`? I can't repo this with 50.

Comment: Can you provide something that runs in the developer console that crashes? I'm unable to repo it on my org.

Comment: @battery.cord see my answer below.  The issue had to do with the `accountIds` set containing only the excluded `opp.AccountId`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a bit of investigation with explicitly stated IDs, I think I found the unique issue that causes the error, and it can be handled more elegantly than my workaround.

Upon further investigation, the error is only happening when `accountIds` contains only `opp.AccountId`.

This fails:

```
[
    SELECT Name
    FROM Account
    WHERE Id != '0014000000SQyVGAA1'
        AND Id != null
        AND (
            Id IN ('0014000000SQyVGAA1')
            OR ParentId IN ('0014000000SQyVGAA1')
            OR Parent.ParentId IN ('0014000000SQyVGAA1')
            OR Parent.Parent.ParentId IN ('0014000000SQyVGAA1')
            OR Parent.Parent.Parent.ParentId IN ('0014000000SQyVGAA1')
        )
    ORDER By Name
]
```

This succeeds:

```
[
    SELECT Name
    FROM Account
    WHERE Id != '0014000000SQyVGAA1'
        AND Id != null
        AND (
            ParentId IN ('0014000000SQyVGAA1')
            OR Parent.ParentId IN ('0014000000SQyVGAA1')
            OR Parent.Parent.ParentId IN ('0014000000SQyVGAA1')
            OR Parent.Parent.Parent.ParentId IN ('0014000000SQyVGAA1')
        )
    ORDER By Name
]
```

And this also succeeds:

```
[
    SELECT Name
    FROM Account
    WHERE Id != '0014000000SQyVGAA1'
        AND Id != null
        AND (
            Id IN ('0014000000VqDVWAA3','0014000000SQyVGAA1')
            OR ParentId IN ('0014000000VqDVWAA3','0014000000SQyVGAA1')
            OR Parent.ParentId IN ('0014000000VqDVWAA3','0014000000SQyVGAA1')
            OR Parent.Parent.ParentId IN ('0014000000VqDVWAA3','0014000000SQyVGAA1')
            OR Parent.Parent.Parent.ParentId IN ('0014000000VqDVWAA3','0014000000SQyVGAA1')
        )
    ORDER By Name
]
```

So the it appears the parser has a hard time dealing with the contradictory inclusion statements.  I can create a second set to eliminate the issue.

One last thing - this succeeds:

```
[
    SELECT Name
    FROM Account
    WHERE Id != '0014000000SQyVGAA1'
        AND Id != null
        AND (
            Id IN ('0014000000SQyVGAA1')
            OR Parent.ParentId IN ('0014000000SQyVGAA1')
        )
    ORDER By Name
]
```

But this fails:

```
[
    SELECT Name
    FROM Account
    WHERE Id != '0014000000SQyVGAA1'
        AND Id != null
        AND (
            Id IN ('0014000000SQyVGAA1')
            OR ParentId IN ('0014000000SQyVGAA1')
            OR Parent.ParentId IN ('0014000000SQyVGAA1')
        )
    ORDER By Name
]
```

So it appears that in order to cause the error, there needs to be both the contradictory statement and at least 2 other inclusion statements within the OR.

Answer (score 2):

Anecdotally, This query runs fine (via the developer consoles query editor) on one of my sandboxes:

```
SELECT Name, ID
FROM Account
WHERE Id != ''
    AND Id != ''
    AND (
        Id IN ('')
        OR ParentId IN ('')
        OR Parent.ParentId IN ('')
        OR Parent.Parent.ParentId IN ('')
        OR Parent.Parent.Parent.ParentId IN ('')
    )
ORDER By Name
```

Using static id lists also works fine:

```
SELECT Name, ID
FROM Account
WHERE Id != '001U000100qh0xJIAQ'
    AND Id != '001U000100qh0xJIAQ'
    AND (
        Id IN ('001U000000ASKzzIAH')
        OR ParentId IN ('001U000000ASKzzIAH')
        OR Parent.ParentId IN ('001U000000ASKzzIAH')
        OR Parent.Parent.ParentId IN ('001U000000ASKzzIAH')
        OR Parent.Parent.Parent.ParentId IN ('001U000000ASKzzIAH')
    )
ORDER By Name
```

Heres some code I used in the developer consoles execute anonymous code window:

```
Id someId = '001U000100qh0xJIAQ';
Id someOtherId = '001U000700qh0xJIAQ';

Set<Id> accountIds = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 1000]).keySet();

System.debug([
    SELECT Name
    FROM Account
    WHERE Id != :someId
        AND Id != :someOtherId
        AND (
            Id IN :accountIds
            OR ParentId IN :accountIds
            OR Parent.ParentId IN :accountIds
            OR Parent.Parent.ParentId IN :accountIds
            OR Parent.Parent.Parent.ParentId IN :accountIds
        )
    ORDER By Name
]);
```

Even trying to look for 1000 items in 4 separate clauses I can't repo your error.

---

Heres the results of running some queries on my org:

```
SELECT Name
FROM Account
WHERE Id != '0014000000SQyVGAA1'
    AND Id != null
    AND (
        Id IN ('0014000000SQyVGAA1')
    )
ORDER By Name
```

> No Results, but no crash.

```
SELECT Name
FROM Account
WHERE Id != '0014000000SQyVGAA1'
    AND Id != null
    AND (
        Id IN ('0014000000SQyVGAA1')
        OR Parent.Parent.ParentId IN ('0014000000SQyVGAA1')
        OR Parent.Parent.Parent.ParentId IN ('0014000000SQyVGAA1')
    )
ORDER By Name
```

> [object Object]: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1038235189-47553 (730406045)

```
SELECT Name
FROM Account
WHERE Id != '0014000000SQyVGAA1'
    AND Id != null
    AND (
        Id IN ('0014000000SQyVGAA1')
        OR Parent.Parent.Parent.ParentId IN ('0014000000SQyVGAA1')
    )
ORDER By Name
```

> No results

```
SELECT Name
FROM Account
WHERE Id != '0014000000SQyVGAA1'
    AND Id != null
    AND (
        Id IN ('0014000000SQyVGAA1')
        OR Parent.Parent.ParentId IN ('0014000000SQyVGAA1')
    )
ORDER By Name
```

> No results.

I have no idea why exactly it fails but it seems like adding that 3rd clause to the `AND` causes the failure. If it was just the `ID != '' && Id == ''` issue, I'd expect the first one to fail.

Comment: I think you meant "repro".

Comment: Exactly my findings.  Always fun to find a weird edge case where things break.

Comment: I dunno, the image of showing up to someone else's place of work, putting some chains around the workstation, tying it to a car, and gunning it to "repo" the error sounds like pretty good entertainment to me. :p